# Wordpress Rest API not working with Postman

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, cookies, postman

I'm using the WordPress REST API plugin. When I visit the API link in Google Chrome, it returns a JSON response as it should, but if I try and use it with Postman, it doesn't work. Instead, it returns this response:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
    <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
        <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("8c438240f47c9d866926316329bd2945");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://adismc.vortekhosting.net/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1?ckattempt=1";
        </script>
        <noscript>This site requires JavaScript to work, please enable JavaScript in your browser or use a browser with JavaScript support</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think it has something to do with cookies, but I'm not sure why it would require cookies for a simple GET request? How do I fix this and get it working with Postman?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? @samir-kahvedzic

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an anti-DDOS/bot protection on your hosting ([example](https://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/102642/ddos-protection-for-website-with-vddos-proxy-protection-vddos-layer4-mapping)). I've solved the problem with changing my hosting.

Probably the protection can be turned off in server settings or you could ask your hosting support.